# Postgres now() timestamp doesn't change, when script works

Tags: php, postgresql

My PHP script will work for several seconds, and I need to get real timestamp from Postgres database anytime. But when I fetch current_timestamp from Postgres, it always return same value.

Here is my example script (using DBAL):

```
    echo "DB:" . $dbal->fetchColumn("select current_timestamp") . PHP_EOL;
    echo "PHP: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(3);

    echo "DB:" . $dbal->fetchColumn("select current_timestamp") . PHP_EOL;
    echo "PHP: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(3);

    echo "DB:" . $dbal->fetchColumn("select current_timestamp") . PHP_EOL;
    echo "PHP: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . PHP_EOL;
```

Here is the output:

```
DB:2014-05-07 11:59:50.118+04
PHP: 2014-05-07 11:59:50

DB:2014-05-07 11:59:50.118+04
PHP: 2014-05-07 11:59:53

DB:2014-05-07 11:59:50.118+04
PHP: 2014-05-07 11:59:56
```

Postgres installed on local machine. Why it always returns same time?
How to get real time?

I used now() function, there was same result. 
Postgres version: 9.3.4 x64. PHP version: 5.5.11

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From [TFM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), highlights mine:

> #### 9.9.4. Current Date/Time
>
> PostgreSQL provides a number of functions that return values related
>   to the current date and time. These SQL-standard functions **all
>   return values based on the start time of the current transaction**:
>
> ```
> CURRENT_DATE
> CURRENT_TIME
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> CURRENT_TIME(precision)
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(precision)
> LOCALTIME
> LOCALTIMESTAMP
> LOCALTIME(precision)
> LOCALTIMESTAMP(precision)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Since these functions return the start time of the current
>   transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This
>   is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction
>   to have a consistent notion of the "current" time, so that multiple
>   modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.
>
> PostgreSQL also provides functions that return the start time of the
>   current statement, as well as the actual current time at the instant
>   the function is called. The complete list of non-SQL-standard time
>   functions is:
>
> ```
> transaction_timestamp()
> statement_timestamp()
> clock_timestamp()
> timeofday()
> now()
> ```
>
> `transaction_timestamp()` is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but is
>   named to clearly reflect what it returns. `statement_timestamp()`
>   returns the start time of the current statement (more specifically,
>   the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client).
>   `statement_timestamp()` and `transaction_timestamp()` return the same
>   value during the first command of a transaction, but might differ
>   during subsequent commands. **`clock_timestamp()` returns the actual
>   current time**, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL
>   command. `timeofday()` is a historical PostgreSQL function. Like
>   `clock_timestamp()`, it returns the actual current time, but as a
>   formatted text string rather than a timestamp with time zone value.
>   **`now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to `transaction_timestamp()`.**

Comment: Maybe worth to highlight `clock_timestamp()`

Comment: Clock_timestamp and statement_timestamp do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @deceze Thank you so much, I was trying to update a timestamp (variable containing now()) defined in a WHILE..LOOP in my plpgsql Procedure and it was NOT updating, so my condition never failed (infinite loop).  I didn't know Timestamps were linked to Transactions. So I added a "commit" after the update of time (var_time := now(); commit;) and everything works fine now