# Postgres: timing the runtime of a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to update an audit table that stores the duration of a function/stored proc,

so far I have

```
drop table if exists tmp_interval_test;
create table tmp_interval_test (
    id serial primary key,
    duration interval
);

drop function if exists tmp_interval;
create or replace function tmp_interval()
    returns void as 

    $body$
    declare
        sleep int;
        start_time timestamp;
        end_time timestamp;
        diff interval;

    begin
        start_time := now();
        sleep := floor(random() * 10 + 1)::int;

        -- actual code goes here
        perform pg_sleep(sleep);
        end_time := now();

        diff := age(end_time, start_time);

        insert into tmp_interval_test (duration) values (diff);
    end;

    $body$
language 'plpgsql' volatile;
```

However, when I test this function, the duration shows

```
id|duration|
--|--------|
 1|00:00:00|
```

How do I correctly insert the duration into my table?

Answer (score 2):

The `now()` functions returns transaction time - it is same inside one transaction. So 0 is correct result. You should to use different functions, that returns real time - Use [`clock_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html) function instead.

On second hand, if you want to collect times of functions, you can use a buildin functionality in Postgres (if has superuser rights). Activate [tracking functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html). Then you can see what you need in system table [`pg_stat_user_function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS).

Answer (score 1):

See [SO regarding now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512172/postgres-now-timestamp-doesnt-change-when-script-works)

Updated function and used `clock_timestamp()` instead of `now()`, e.g.,

```
start_time := clock_timestamp();
```

Comment: current_timestamp cannot to help, it returns transaction time again - and there is syntax error - it is pseudoconstant. Postgres functions are running under transaction every time.

Comment: You want `clock_timestamp()`

Comment: yes I do sorry I meant to put `clock_timestamp()` sorry will fix this