# postgres initializing a variable in a do block

Tags: postgresql, function, block, plpgsql

On a very basic level in a do block in Postgres I want to call a function and get the value and do necessary updates - but it looks like the first time i call the function from the block it gets initialized and does not update subsequently.

I have tried breaking up the block and have sub blocks - no luck. Below is a very simple example :

```
do $$
<<outer_block>>
declare
    _counter int := 0 ;
begin
    while _counter < 5
        loop
            declare _now timestamp := getTime(); --now();
            begin
                raise notice 'COUNTER : % TIME STAMP : %' , _counter, _now;
            end;
            _counter := _counter + 1;
            perform pg_sleep(5);
        end loop;
end outer_block $$;
```

and getTime is ...

```
create or replace function getTime() returns timestamp   --setof record 
language plpgsql
as 
$$
declare
    _val timestamp := now();
begin
--  _val := now();
    return _val;
end $$;
```

The output of the main block is the same time stamp.

**Is it because Postgres instead of being sequential sends the entire block as an object and therefore the time stamp is the same?**

Could I add an insert in the function to a temp table and have a trigger update another table to get the time stamp (or new initialized value ?)

**Output of the main block is:**

```
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 0 TIME STAMP : 2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432
NOTICE:  2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432-04
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 1 TIME STAMP : 2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432
NOTICE:  2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432-04
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 2 TIME STAMP : 2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432
NOTICE:  2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432-04
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 3 TIME STAMP : 2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432
NOTICE:  2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432-04
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 4 TIME STAMP : 2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432
NOTICE:  2021-03-15 19:03:07.73432-04
DO
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Postgres now() timestamp doesn't change, when script works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512172/postgres-now-timestamp-doesnt-change-when-script-works), you can try `timeofday()` instead of `now()`;

```
edb=# create or replace function getTime() returns timestamp   --setof record 
language plpgsql
as 
$$                     
declare
    _val timestamp := timeofday();
begin
--  _val := timeofday();
    return _val;
end $$ volatile;
CREATE FUNCTION
edb=# do $$                                                                   
<<outer_block>>
declare
    _counter int := 0 ;
begin
    while _counter < 5
        loop
            declare _now timestamp := getTime(); --now();
            begin
                raise notice 'COUNTER : % TIME STAMP : %' , _counter, _now;
            end;
            _counter := _counter + 1;
            perform pg_sleep(5);
        end loop;
end outer_block $$;
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 0 TIME STAMP : 15-MAR-21 23:44:17.870405
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 1 TIME STAMP : 15-MAR-21 23:44:22.875366
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 2 TIME STAMP : 15-MAR-21 23:44:27.880828
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 3 TIME STAMP : 15-MAR-21 23:44:32.886212
NOTICE:  COUNTER : 4 TIME STAMP : 15-MAR-21 23:44:37.891187
DO
```

Comment: I would recommend `clock_timestamp()` rather than converting the timestamp to `text` and back.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I really appreciate the response - i was stuck on trying to do this in a loop and tried now() - but thank you.